# Exporting to CSV giving me extra rows each time

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

What I'm trying to do is feed in my CSV file into a datatable and then loop through and resave it as a csv, stripping away the quotes around all the values so I can LEFT JOIN the values with another csv.

Upon the first export, it works fine. If I happen to run it again it adds a new column called "No Name". If I run it again it'll add yet another "No Name" tab and so on. Here is my code so far.

```
            Dim currentrow As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            Dim entirefile As New System.Text.StringBuilder

            Dim i As Integer = 0

            For Each column As DataColumn In dt1.Columns
                currentrow.Append("" & column.ColumnName & ",")
            Next
            entirefile.AppendLine(currentrow.ToString)

            For Each row As DataRow In dt1.Rows
                currentrow = New System.Text.StringBuilder
                i = 0
                For Each column As DataColumn In dt1.Columns
                    currentrow.Append("" & row.Item(i) & ",")
                    i += 1
                Next
                entirefile.AppendLine(currentrow.ToString)
            Next

            Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\CSV\MlnExp.csv")
            sw.Write(entirefile)
            sw.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra columns are arising as a result of these lines:

```
currentrow.Append("" & column.ColumnName & ",")

currentrow.Append("" & row.Item(i) & ",")
```

You're appending a column name or field along with a trailing comma. After the last item you're left with a trailing comma that you're not removing, so the system sees an extra blank field at the end of the line.

All you need to do is strip the trailing commas after you finish assembling the line.

I think this should work for you:

```
currentrow.Length = currentRow.Length-1    ' shorten row by 1 character
entirefile.AppendLine(currentrow.ToString)
```

Comment: What language is? I'm usually familiar with C# but I'm doing VB on this specific project

Comment: I know how to do it with a string, you'd just do a `.Substring(0, strExport.Length - 1)` but I'm not too familiar with string builders.

Comment: I've update my answer with something that should work in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding the comma (`... & ",")`) in both lines of your `For` cycles.

Consider removing the last comma or not adding one in the last pass of the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
        For Each column As DataColumn In dt1.Columns
            currentrow.Append("" & column.ColumnName & ",")
        Next
```

and this:

```
            For Each column As DataColumn In dt1.Columns
                currentrow.Append("" & row.Item(i) & ",")
                i += 1
            Next
```

You are appending a trailing `","` at the end of each row.  I'm assuming at this point you are feeding the same MlnExp.csv file that you are generating into the next run of the program.

By adding the trailing comma, you are adding a new field to your row each time, and running repeatedly like this is appending multiple columns.

My typical solution is to instead prepend a comma before each subsequent column.
i.e.

```
            dim first as boolean = true
            For Each column As DataColumn In dt1.Columns
                if not first then currentrow.Append(",")
                currentrow.Append("" & row.Item(i))
                first = false
                i += 1
            Next
```

A little crude, but usually gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just missing something, but why not just read the csv in as a string and do a replace statement... Something along the lines of replacing the `","` with just `,` (and extra replacements for start and end of lines... there are plenty of examples of how to do this) and not even bother with creating a datatable then writing from it in the first place???

Would that work for you???